# remove autogenerated DIVs in TYPO3

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

Have search the net and can't find a solution.
If im make a page in TYPO3 and add some content, i end up with this.

```
<div id="clear"> </div>


    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:4/html [begin] -->
        <div id="c4" class="csc-default">
        <!--  Raw HTML content: [begin] -->
            <div id="topbilled_om"></div>
        <!--  Raw HTML content: [end] -->
            </div>
    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:4/html [end] -->


    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:2/html [begin] -->
        <div id="c2" class="csc-default">
        <!--  Raw HTML content: [begin] -->
            <div id="LeftColumn">
```

And what i want is this

```
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="topbilled_om"></div>
    <div id="LeftColumn"></div>
```

How do i skip the extra added div's, my problem is that its make an error in my design, bc of the extra added div's ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the innerWrap of a cObject:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
```

Yet I do not recommend it. It looks like you're trying to use HTML element as some kind of placeholders. You could use a field like "layout" (in the page properties) to define custom wraps instead of csc-default, e.g.:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {

  key.field = layout

  1 = TEXT
  1.value = <div class="my-layout-1">|</div>

  2 = TEXT
  2.value = <div class="my-layout-2">|</div>

}
```

and rename the layout in the backend:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
  layout.altLabels.1 = My Layout 1
  layout.altLabels.2 = My Layout 2
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With TYPO3 7.6 and an enabled `fluid_styled_content` extension, this comes from `fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/ContentFooter.html`.

You have to add your own layout path in typoscript:

```
lib.fluidContent.layoutRootPaths.100 = EXT:foo/Resources/Private/Layouts/
```

and then copy and adjust the `ContentFooter.html` file in your extension.

Comment: For TYPO3 9.5 use  `lib.contentElement.layoutRootPaths.100 = EXT:foo/Resources/Private/Layouts/`. The template is now in `Default.html` of `fluid_styled_content` that should be copied and changed to adjust wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

To remove comments disable them in your TS template:

```
page.config.disablePrefixComment = 1
```

To disable `csc-*` frames you can set it manually to the `No frame` on `Appearance` tab of each `tt_content` or better just set it as default with PageTS of root page:

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.section_frame=66
```

Finally you can just overwrite whole CSC (CSS Styled Content) in your own template to remove unwanted wraps.

Comment: I did as you described - and got rid of both comments and div frames. However, a new tag was added, for example: `<a id="c106"></a>`. Any ideas?

Comment: @bernland This one occures when there's no frame it's for pointing where the section menu should target